# the painting was glazed

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, american-english, british-english, dialect

In the following passge, is "glazed" a US usage?

> The two young women from the campaign group Just Stop Oil threw the contents of two tins of Heinz tomato soup over the painting, which, the group said , has an estimated value of $84.2 million.

> ..."There is some minor damage to the frame but the painting is unharmed," it said. In a subsequent tweet, the gallery explained that the painting was **glazed** and therefore protected.

https://edition.cnn.com/style/article/oil-protest-van-gogh-sunflower-soup-intl-scli-gbr/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Not particularly American.  It means that there is a sheet of glass in front of the painting. The ultimate source here is a tweet from the (British) National gallery:

> **Rob Padley** Is there glass over the painting?
>
> **National Gallery** Hi Rob, the painting is glazed.

Comment: Is it a usage unique to British English?

Comment: Probably not.  "glazed" meaning "fitted with glass" is the normal meaning of the word.

Comment: But normally one fits a frame with glass. Is a painting a frame that can be fitted with glass?

Comment: That painting has a frame which could (as is) fitted with glass.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but that takes some stretching. Strictly it is the frame of the painting that is glazed. I'd like to see if this stretching is also available in American English.

Comment: Just like you'd say 'the window is glazed', even though it's strictly the frame. It's not even really a window until it's glazed, it's just a hole in the wall. Double glazing is two sheets of glass that make up an insulated window. [Triple exists too, for colder climes.]

Comment: @DoneWithThis. "Window" itself can refer to a space: In Cambridge Dictionary, "window" is defined as "a  space  usually  filled  with  glass  in the  wall  of a  building  or in a  vehicle  , to  allow   light  and  air  in and to  allow   people  inside the  building  to  see  out"

Comment: It makes sense to fit a hole with glass as long as it has edges.

Comment: …and there you just explained why the paining is glazed ;)) The terminology is pretty loose.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. In British English, maybe. But in American English, I'm not sure. (And I didn't explain why the painting is glazed. I was only saying "glaze a window" makes perfect sense as the window can only be a hole, which can of course be fitted with glass.)

Comment: If  "painting" were defined in any dictionaries as a "hole," then I would have explained why the painting is glazed.

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can add. "The terminology is pretty loose." This is the essential point to take away.

Answer (score 0):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/glazed#:%7E:text=(%C9%A1leizd)-,adjective,fitted%20or%20set%20with%20glass) does list it as American English:

> glazed
> in American English
> (ɡleizd)
> ADJECTIVE

1. having a surface covered with a glaze; lustrous; smooth; glassy

But other dictionaries don't. The only difference I saw is that in American dictionaries such as *[Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/glazed)* or [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glazed) the meaning of ***A thin smooth shiny coating*** comes first, while in the others it is listed last (see [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glazed))

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glazed%20painting%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cglazed%20painting%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) will show you that it is used by both sides of the pond.

Comment: The "In American English" label on Collins isn't particular reliable. It it used even for British expressions like "vac" (meaning "vacation")

Comment: Yes, that's why I said that the other dictionaries don't label it that way.

Comment: That is a slightly different sense of "glazed". It refers to (for example) pottery that is "painted" with a thin layer of colour, which is then melted onto the pot in the kiln. Most pottery for food is glazed.

Comment: Surely, "glazed painting" is used on both sides of the pond, but it remains to be see whether the expression is used with the same meanings in both places. For example, "glazed painting" can refer to a painting coated with some shiny material, but it is not the sense used in the CNN article.